# Assigning Private Property values

Tags: petapoco

I'm testing out PetaPoco to determine if it meets our needs.  I was under the impression that it would delve into my class and see the private properties that I've marked up as valid columns.  Unfortunately, it's not behaving as expected.   Can you please take a look and let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

My test class:

```
Imports PetaPoco

<PetaPoco.TableName("PaulTest")>
<PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("ID")>
Public Class PaulTest

    <PetaPoco.Column("ID")>
    Private Property pvtID As Integer
    Private pvtName As String

    Private Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Passed Name is empty")
        End If

        Me.pvtName = name

    End Sub

    <PetaPoco.Ignore>
    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return pvtID
        End Get
    End Property

    <PetaPoco.Column("Name")>
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return pvtName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("Passed Name is empty")
            End If

            Me.pvtName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

The call to the DB (_db is a PetaPoco database object)

```
Return (_db.Fetch(Of Peta.Domain.PaulTest)(";EXEC selAllPaulTest")).OrderBy(Function(PaulTest) (PaulTest.ID)).ToList()
```

What's in the database

```
ID  Name
107 Paul
```

What's being returned:

```
PaulTest.ID = 0
PaulTest.pvtID = 0
PaulTest.Name = "Paul"
PaulTest.pvtName = "Paul"
```

Comment: Why are you using a such a complicated design?

Comment: Not sure which part you are considering complicated so I'll just explain the reasoning behind the private ID.    I want the consumer of my class to only be able to modify the Name property and not the ID.  But I want them to be able to read the ID.

Comment: Oh, I see now, still little convoluted IMO. Back to the problem, are you using PetaPoco 4?

Comment: I'm using what's on Nuget and it's Version 5.0.1 Last published 03/02/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<PetaPoco.Ignore>` attribute instructs `PetaPoco` to ignore the column during mapping. As such, the property `Id` will always be returning the default value of 0.

If you want to prevent the `Id` property from being modified, comment our or delete the attribute and add a private setter to the `Id` property as in the following code snippet.

```
' <PetaPoco.Ignore>
    Public Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return pvtID
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Integer)
            pvtID = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Ah I see now.  Thank you.  That also explains why Eduardo was saying it was convoluted.